# updating the few highest rows in a table using mysql 5.1.41

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with several hundred rows. I want to take the top 20 based on the value of column `num` and replace `num` with a number.

What I tried to do (which didn't work) was:

```
UPDATE table
SET num = 95
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the subquery - you can [use LIMIT in an UPDATE statement on MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html):

```
  UPDATE table
     SET num = 95
ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

It's unclear what you want to order by - I used `id` based on your subquery, but in case it needs to be by the `num` value:

```
  UPDATE table
     SET num = 95
ORDER BY num DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds. I think it should be sorted by `num` though.

Comment: @Mike: You had a whole 17 minutes! :p  Added the sort by num alternative, I was basing off the subquery the OP posted.

Comment: I wasn't aware that limit and order by worked in updates, thanks.

Comment: @tipu: That's why I linked to the documentation for MySQL UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try a small change:

```
UPDATE table
SET num = 95
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 20)
```

If you want to get the top 20 num's, you need to sort by num's.

Comment: Good catch. The problem lies in the subquery's use of LIMIT, however. I will try this in any case. Edit: It's still complaining about the use of LIMIT in the subquery.

Comment: Can you run the subquery on its own?

Comment: Yes. The error is that my version of MySQL does not support LIMIT in the subquery